# Make a custom button invisible based on a field value

Tags: salesforce

How can we make a custom button visible based an the status of a field on a standard layout ( not a visualforce page) in a custom object.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a tutorial by Tehnrd:
http://www.tehnrd.com/show-and-hide-buttons-on-page-layouts/

Answer (score 0):

This is possible leveraging record types and a unique page layout for each. The jQuery solution posted by Matthew looks really cool though.